# rendering content using css content property

Tags: html, css

if I'm rendering right arrow in html like `&#x25ba` why I cannot render it using css class using following?

```
.arrow-right  {    
    content: '&#x25ba';
}

<i class="arrow-right"></i>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to what others wrote about using `:before` or `:after` pseudoselectors, `content` cannot contain HTML, and by extension it can't contain entities: you need to write

```
.arrow-right:before {
    content: '►';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can, but you must specify "before" or "after" and use the slash notation to make it work:

```css
    .arrow-right:after  {    
        content: '\2192';
    }
```

```html
<i class="arrow-right"></i>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `content` property is used only with the `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements. It can't be used with elements.

You can change your styles:

```
.arrow-right::before {    
    content: '&#x25ba';
}
```

[More in MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/content)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `after` or `before` `pseudo selectors` in class definition

```css
.arrow-right:after {    
    //content: "\2192";
     content: "→";
}
```

```html
<i class="arrow-right"></i>
```